# How do I stop Microsoft Teams from spewing itself all across my Windows environment?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I recently did a factory restore of Windows 11 on a laptop.  The factory-provided image basically provided Windows 11, Office, and minimal bloatware.  I created a local user account to sign in with.

The first application I installed was Microsoft Teams.  I explicitly chose "do not let my organisation manage my device".  Despite this, the following happened after I logged into Teams using my work account:

- Microsoft Office products were activated with my company's licence.  The default cloud user in Office was changed to my work account -- the same account I logged into Teams with.
- My "recent" shortcuts were updated to several cloud documents I recently worked on at the office.
- My desktop (and likely other folders) started being backed up to the company's backup service.

This is what I noticed within 5 minutes of installation.  I am sure there are other things as well.

I explicitly chose "do not manage my device" because I *do not* want Teams to spew itself all over my personal laptop.  Is there some option to stop this from happening?

Comment: Perhaps you should not use your company's license on your personal laptop. WIn11 would not know the company license unless you put it there.

Comment: @doneal24 All the licences are my own.  Office automatically changed to the company's licences after installing teams.

Comment: Did the license code magically float through the ether to your laptop? How did a factory image manager to know the company license information?

Comment: @doneal24 Again, this happened after I installed Teams and logged into my work account in Teams.  Something in Teams applied the company's site-wide licence to Office.  Among other things.

Comment: Office365 is a single account for Teams, OneDrive, Office, etc. You signed in using your work account, and the other apps all share automatically. You'll need to use teams in the browser if you don't want that to happen. You can remove the account/device registration under your account > Devices at https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list

Comment: Or, in any of the Office apps like Word, go to File > Office Account > Switch account, and sign into your personal office account

Comment: You never said you logged into your work account - that is an important piece of information. Did you just use the Teams login or was something else involved, e.g. Office 365, OneDrive, domain login, etc?

Comment: @doneal24 Just teams.  The windows login was the local user I created.

Comment: 1. Office being activated by your work email is normal if you also log into Teams an Office product.  2. The recent shortcuts is a result of you logging into your work email within Office.  This is also normal and expected. Your desktop is being synchronized because of your OneDrive settings.  This is also expected. and perfectly normal.  The first two are expected and there is no real solution to them.  You can avoid 3 by simply NOT choosing to synchronize your desktop to OneDrive.

Answer (score -1):

It appears you either signed in with a company account, possibly joining the domain, and the computer is syncing that account. You can just try signing off the company Microsoft Teams account. For the computer, it appears you may be using OneDrive which is why you are obtaining company information on your desktop and your backup service is backing up that information as well.

I would suggest you unjoin your company domain after deleting all the unwanted shortcuts as well as logging out of office.com accounts on that computer.

Comment: I will double check to see if my computer was added to my company's domain.  But if this is what happened, how would I stop Teams from doing that?  This was off a fresh Windows restore with a Lenovo image, the only Windows account that would have been known to the computer before I installed teams was the local account I created.

Comment: I'm definitely not a ChatBot nor did I use ChatGPT. In addition, asking about the company account was only a portion of my Q/A. Did ChatGPT give you your username?